# Pigeon hole principle for Graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, pigeonhole-principle

There is a Simple Graph G with 10 vertices and 28 edges. I need to show that there exist two vertices whose sum of degrees is at least 12.

My attempt:

The sum of all the degrees of vertices must be 28*2 = 56. I understand that we should use pigeon hole principle to proceed but I have no idea what to take as pigeons and what to take as pigeon holes. Kindly please help on how I can proceed further.

Comment: If all $10$ vertices have degrees $5$ or fewer, then the sum of degrees would be only $50$ or fewer.

Comment: I don't know what this has to do with pigeonholes, but if a simple graph of order $10$ has degree sequence $d_1\ge d_2\ge d_3\ge d_4\ge d_5\ge d_6\ge d_7\ge d_8\ge d_9\ge d_{10}$, and if $d_1+d_2\lt12$, then $d_3+\cdots+d_{10}\le5+5+\cdots+5=40$, so $d_1+d_2+d_3+\cdots+d_{10}\lt12+40=52$, so the graph has at most $25$ edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by pure [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), though it's a bit tricky.

There are $45$ pair of vertices $(i, j)$. Let $d_{i, j}$ be the sum of degrees of vertices $i$ and $j$.

When we add one edge, the sum of $d_{i, j}$ will be increased by $18$. For example, when we add edge $1-2$:

- $d_{1, 2}$ will be increased by $2$,
- $d_{1, 3}, d_{1, 4}, \dots, d_{1, 10}$ will be increased by $1$, and
- $d_{2, 3}, d_{2, 4}, \dots, d_{2, 10}$ will be increased by $1$.

Therefore, if we add $28$ edges, the sum of $d_{i, j}$ will be $18 \times 28 = 504$. Then, it can be translated into this scenario:

> There are $45$ holes and $504$ pigeons inside these holes. Show that at least one hole has $12$ or more pigeons.

This is true by pigeonhole principle, because $\lceil 504/45 \rceil = 12$.